# Would it be possible to design a dart-like object such that it survives re-entry and impact at interplanetary / interstellar speeds?

Tags: energy, mass, material-science, space

I was wondering about spacecraft - specifically just getting from point A to B. If you were unconcerned about human survival and damage from g-forces, it would be much easier to deliver it without the need to decelerate.

For example if you wanted to transport materials like steel from one planet to another, it could be more cost-effective to just impact it and retrieve it (but tell me if I'm wrong).

So could you design a dart or something alike to do this? Or is the kinetic energy just too great?

Answer (score 1):

The key words here are "survive" and "useful".

Typical interplanetary speeds are tens of km/s, interstellar speeds hundreds of km/s (unless we start bringing in relativistic transport). These are all supersonic in molecular matter and that means that the dart impact at first only affect the matter ahead of it - stuff to the sides have not yet got the signal that something changes. So the dart will penetrate straight in, but since the compressed material ahead and in the dart gets heated to gas or plasma the depth of penetration will deviate from the [Newton impact formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_depth) in complex ways. Basically it all turns into an explosion, leaving a crater with a diameter [roughly proportional](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0734743X9599832C) to velocity.

So the material is there, it is just that it gets mixed with whatever it hit, is a gas or fine particles, and is now moving in all directions. Is this useful? Depends mostly on your application.